# scanf output has a little wrong

Tags: c, scanf

```
int studentId,nOfWorkingDay;
char name[30],surname[30]; 
printf("Enter person information : name , surname ,studentId, nOfWorkingDay\n");
scanf("%s %s %d %d",&name,&surname,&studentId,&nOfWorkingDay);
printf("%s %s %d %d",name,surname,studentId,nOfWorkingDay);
```

I get a strange output.  For example, when I enter:

```
birol genç 30 35
```

the output is:

```
birol gen┼ 30 35
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: another example I enter: buğra kara 12 30 output:bu§ra kara 12 30

Comment: Not again. Check the return value of scanf. Also format parameters so you so not get buffer overruns

Comment: Related: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Which platform are you on?  Which code set is in effect?  FWIW: on Mac OS X 10.11.1 with GCC 5.2.0 and with UTF-8 as the code set, the code works OK, reproducing the input on output (after I added a newline to the output).  That means the problem is somewhat platform specific, and quite possibly depends in part on the code set that is in use.

Comment: I am writing on windows 10 with devc++

Comment: @JonathanLeffler now I understand you and deleted some lines    #include <locale.h>                                              setlocale(LC_ALL,"Turkish");                                                                             but now there is now big problem I printed many names and surnames true with this lines ,if I delete this lines the scanf output will okay but others will wrong

Comment: Also, again FWIW, the ç translates to UTF-8 bytes 0xC3 0xA7 = U+00E7 = LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA; the ┼ translates to UTF-8 bytes 0xE2 0x94 0xBC = U+253C = BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT VERTICAL AND
HORIZONTAL.  I don't yet have a good explanation of what's going on.

Comment: Turkish?  That's fun.  Is it CP 1254 that you're using?  You may find some information here: http://czyborra.com/charsets/codepages.html — it identifies CP 1254 as WinTurkish.  I haven't needed to work with this before, and I don't have Windows to test anything on.  I took your code and added just `#include <stdio.h>`, and `int main(void) {` before and `return 0; }` after your code.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%s %s %d %d",&name,&surname,&studentId,&nOfWorkingDay);` should be

`scanf("%s %s %d %d", name, surname,&studentId,&nOfWorkingDay);`

ie, remove the `&` before `name` and `surname` which are already addresses of the character strings.

Comment: True, but not the cause of the problem.

Comment: How does your Answer, answer the OPs Question? The OPs Question was about that Output, not about how to use scanf.

Comment: fair enough - his `scanf` is clearly an issue though, he needs to fix that first before going any futher

Comment: Curiously enough, even though the type of `&name` is `char (*)[30]` instead of `char *`, the bit pattern of `(void *)&name` and `(void *)name` is the same, so the code 'works', even though the invocation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
int studentId,nOfWorkingDay;
char name[30],surname[30]; 
printf("Enter person information : name , surname ,studentId,nOfWorkingDay\n");
scanf("%s %s %d %d",name,surname,&studentId,&nOfWorkingDay);
printf("%s %s %d %d",name,surname,studentId,nOfWorkingDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

int studentId,nOfWorkingDay;
char name[30],surname[30]; 
printf("Enter person information : name , surname ,studentId,nOfWorkingDay\n");
scanf("%s %s %d %d",name,surname,&studentId,&nOfWorkingDay);
printf("%s %s %d %d",name,surname,studentId,nOfWorkingDay);
}
```

description:

scanf("%s",firstname);

The %s placeholder is used to read in text, but only until the first white space character is encountered. So a space or a tab or the Enter key terminates the string. (That sucks.) Also, firstname is a char array, so it doesn’t need the & operator in the scanf() function.

Comment: How does your Answer, answer the OPs Question? The OPs Question was about that Output, not about how to use scanf.

Comment: fair enough - his scanf is clearly an issue though, he needs to fix that first before going any futher